# Selenium webdriver support for the latest versions of firefox and chrome

Tags: python, google-chrome, firefox, selenium

I am using selenium-2.35.0 and Python-2.7.
Testcases are written in python.

my python code to create driver object:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities={
    "browserName": "firefox"
})
```

And run selenium server by,

```
java - jar selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar
```

I had my code working in Firefox - 22 - had the selenium server running, able to run scripts in python, etc. So I'm confident the code works.

Recently, I updated FireFox to 23 and now all I get is

"[Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."

I thought maybe I need to restart the server again, or something. But that seems to do nothing. Is this issue related to selenium webdriver's support for the latest browser version?

But as of this link http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/java/CHANGELOG , selenium supports Firefox - 23. If supported, code that run in Firefox - 22 should also run in Firefox - 23 without any code change.

And how can i make the same code work for chrome?

Answer (score 1):

I have found that the newest version of firefox routinely doens't work immediately well with Selenium.  Check out this [firefox support matrix on Github](https://github.com/santiycr/selenium-firefox-support-matrix) that someone made.  Unfortunately the only thing you can do is [stop Firefox from auto-updating](http://watirmelon.com/2013/05/16/stop-firefox-auto-updating-and-breaking-your-ci-build/) and keep your selenium tests running for firefox newest version minus 1 or 2.  Chrome tends to work out of the box for Selenium, sometimes the Beta channel has fixed some selenium issues, so try that if you have a particular issue (on the other hand it may introduce other bugs).  So in the end you need to be constantly weary of browser updates and routinely checking how they are working with the current version of selenium.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this guide on how to get Selenium working with rolled back versions of firefox: 
http://inkhorn.ca/selenium-python-on-ubuntu-using-firefox/

It will also fix any errors that have to do with “version xul**.0 not defined in file libxul.so”